# Problem with Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler on Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, autoscaling

I have kubernetes cluster running on Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set. I use Kubernetes Cluster Autoscaler to scale the number of nodes. It works fine, if i set limit from 1 to 10 but the problem appears when i set limit from **0** in one particular case:

When the number of nodes has been scaled to 0 and after this operation pod with cluster autoscaler restarted. Then i want to run pod on this VMSS (pod with nodeSelector - **agentpool: memory**), but it looks like autoscaler can't read appropriate labels from VMSS when number of instance is scaled to 0.

According to documentation i add the following tag to the VMSS `k8s.io_cluster-autoscaler_node-template_label_agentpool: memory`.

I have logs from autoscaler pod:

```
GeneralPredicates predicate mismatch, reason: node(s) didn't match node selector
```